# How do I grab the div that the a tag was clicked

Tags: jquery

How do I grab the div that the a tag was clicked and clone it and insert into another div.

I just really need to know how to grab the parent div something like this a parent div

```
                      <div class="seven columns offset-by-one">
                            <h1>
                                Joshua F. Schwartz
                            </h1>
                            <h2>
                                Position
                            </h2>
                            <p>
                            venenatis nisl ut lorem ultricies semper.
                            Duis vitae turpis nec tortor dignissim tempor.
                            Phasellus et elit et.
                            <a href="">Read More</a>
                            </p>
                      </div>
```

Heres is my code Based off of your guys comments below Thanks so much your responds
 have been great so far , but for some reason it doesn't work. :(

//// Select Link     On click Run Function
    $("#leaderBottom a").on("click", function(event) {
      ///Prevent link execution 
      event.preventDefault();

```
    ///insert dark overlay
    $('<div class="overlay"></div>').insertAfter('#leaderTop');
        // show block
      $('.popOut').css('display','block');
      /// Grab the links div

        var $newDiv = $(this).parent('.four').clone();
         $newDiv.appendTo('.popOut');
            return false;



      });
```

Comment: jQuery's .parent(): http://api.jquery.com/parent/

Comment: Or .closest() if it's not the immediate parent: http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: If you used [`Google`](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+parent&aq=0&oq=jquery+parent&aqs=chrome.0.0j60j0l3j62.1651j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), you would find the answer in seconds...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's your call, but I would actually use `.parents()` to achieve what you're trying (since you can provide a selector):

```
$('a').click(function() {
    var $cloned = $(this).parents('.seven').clone();
    $cloned.appendTo('.clone-wrapper');
    return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MXHS6/

Comment: $("#leaderBottom a").on("click", function(event) {
      ///Prevent link execution 
      event.preventDefault();

        ///insert dark overlay
        $('<div class="overlay"></div>').insertAfter('#leaderTop');
            // show block
          $('.popOut').css('display','block');
          /// Grab the links div

            var newDiv = $(this).parents().clone();
             $newDiv.appendTo('.popOut');
                return false;



          
    });   This is my code, but its not working. What Does return false do?

Comment: Try `newDiv.appendTo('.popOut');` instead of `$newDiv.appendTo('.popOut');` .. `return false;` simply prevents default anchor behavior (similarly to preventDefault());

Comment: `.parents()` will select ALL parent elements that match the selector. To get the closest parent that matches, you want `.closest()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) to find that div.

$("a").parent(".seven .columns .offset-by-one");

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
<div class="seven columns offset-by-one">
    <h1>
        Joshua F. Schwartz
    </h1>
    <h2>
        Position
    </h2>
    <p>
       venenatis nisl ut lorem ultricies semper.
       Duis vitae turpis nec tortor dignissim tempor.
       Phasellus et elit et.
       <a class='ReadMore' href="">Read More</a>
    </p>
</div>


$(".ReadMore").bind("click", function () {
    var newDiv = $(this).parent().clone();
});
```

Comment: This will select the `<p>` around the `<a>`, not the `<div>`